# Issue using quickCheckAll and GHC 7.10.1 RC1

Tags: haskell, ghc, quickcheck

The following example compiles with GHC 7.8.4 and QuickCheck 2.7.6:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Test.QuickCheck

prop_id :: Eq a => a -> Bool
prop_id x = x == x

-- Hack to make $quickCheckAll work under GHC >= 7.8.
return []

main :: IO Bool
main = $quickCheckAll
```

Using GHC 7.10.1 RC 1, I got the following error:

```
$ ghc Bug.hs
Bug.hs:12:8:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      Higher-kinded type variables in type: forall (a_0 :: *) . GHC.Classes.Eq a_0 => a_0 -> GHC.Types.Bool
    Code: quickCheckAll
   In the splice: $quickCheckAll
```

Can I fix the example using some conditional compilation? Or is the issue related to the QuickCheck library?

Comment: It definitely looks like some sort of Template Haskell issue. Are you using the bleeding-edge QuickCheck sources from git or darcs (whatever they use)? If not, try that. If so, report a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in QuickCheck (see https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/issues/42).